# Remoting into a Hyper-V VM with Powershell 2.0 Never able to find VM

Tags: .net, powershell, windows-server-2008, remoting, powershell-remoting

I'm currently playing around with Powershell 2.0 and have run into the following issue. I've set up a Hyper-V VM and I'm trying to remote into it from my native/host OS.

I've been following this tutorial on remoting: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_remote.htm#Create_a_PowerShell_Remote_Session

When I use the following PS command to remote into my VM which as a fully qualified domain foo:
    Enter-PSSession foo

I get an error along the lines of PS not being able to find the computer. I've made sure that Network Discovery is enabled and remote access is enabled on the VM but still run into the same issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: May I suggest you to use the IP Address and see if that works?

Comment: Please try IP address instead and it should work if the problem is related with FQDN. If that did not work then you have some other problem.

Comment: Using the IP address worked. Any idea why the FQDN doesn't work?

Comment: great, i was expecting the same. Is your Hyper-V VM is connected with Domain Controller or standalone box or USER Group, FQDN will be different in each case. What you can do is to get the FQDN name in your  network by pinging it which will return FQDN.

Answer (score 0):

First, check what port is your RM running on (from command line on target system):

```
winrm e winrm/config/listener
```

If this running not on port `5985` you will have to specify port when connecting

Check if connection is fine by running "ping" command from the client:

```
Test-WSMan -ComputerName "full machine name"
```

If it doesn't help - post your output from both commands. BTW, I hope you have proper network configuration in your VM, I mean it has its own name and IP?

Answer (score 0):

First Please try IP address instead and it should work if the are using incorrect FQDN.

Once your IP address worked means your target VM needs no network setting etc and you just need to get the correct FQDN and here is something you can try.

For example when I ping to a machine name XYZ as below:

```
ping xyz
```

It will return machine FQDN as below or something similar:

```
Pinging xyz.abc.corp.com
```

In above case "xyz.abc.corp.com" is the correct FQDN and if you are getting "Pinging xyz" only then "xyz" is your FQDN.